# Similar but incompatible classes

Tags: c++, oop

What is a good practice for the following problem (in C++ foremost)?

I want to implement two (and later more) classes that are very similar but should be incompatible. For example I'll name them `class Apple` and `class Orange`. Obviously, then have common properties, like species, age, location and whatnot, but a apple object should never be assigned to an orange variable.

More importantly: there should be member functions that accept (or return) the own class and never the others. For example, the class Apple would have: `Apple[] getAllFromTheSameTree();` and the class Orange would have: `Orange[] getAllFromTheSameTree();` Also something like `void addToSameTree(Apple)` etc, having in mind that apples can not be on the same tree as oranges.

One idea is to have an abstract root class (`class Fruit`) that would define the common properties. But that would allow a function to accept a `Fruit` type parameter, which I want to prohibit - if possible).

Another idea is templates: `Fruit<Apple>` and `Fruit<Orange>` (Apple and Orange would be some dummy empty types here).

Comment: What about having a fully abstract base class, with deleted default constructors?

Comment: Your question attracts opinionated answers and is (probably) off-topic.

Comment: Private inheritance?

Comment: Why do you want to prohibit writing a function that takes the common base? This sounds like over-design. If you don't need a function like that, don't write it. If you do need it, don't prohibit it.

Comment: Really you are asking "Is Object-oriented design a good idea". The answer is often "no", but as Raw N said, it's too much of a contentious issue for here.

Comment: @PeteBecker What you said sounds like "Why use encapsulation? Just don't write code that accesses the hidden items."

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean What do you mean? I does not need to be OOP/D, but OOP/D seems to be a good way to do the above (different types sharing properties).

Comment: @DavidBalažic -- encapsulation solves an otherwise difficult problem. "I want to derive from a base class but not allow writing a function that takes the base class" does not. If calling a function with a `Fruit&` is harmless (even if pointless) there's no reason to want to prohibit it. If it's harmful then you've got a serious design problem, and local hacks like prohibiting such a call don't address the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

> One idea is to have an abstract root class (class Fruit) that would define the common properties

Yep, that's the ideea I advise you with.

> But that would allow a function to accept a Fruit type parameter,
>   which I want to prohibit - if possible).

Well, that's a non-issue. Because being abstract, there can't be objects of type `Fruit`

E.g. a function with this signature:

```
void consume_fruit(Fruit& fruit)
```

Will accept any kind of fruit (`Apple`, `Orange`). And since `Fruit` is abstract it won't accept objects of type `Fruit` simply because objects of type `Fruit` cannot exist.

Similarity a collection e.g. `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Fruit>>` would hold objects of types derived from `Fruit` (`Apple`, `Orange`) but again there can't be objects of type `Fruit`.

Comment: `Apple.addToSameTree(Orange)` would be accepted by your solution, but I don't want that. That is a major requirement. Just like I don't want it so accept `std::string` or any other type. I want it to be a compiler error, visible right in the IDE editor.

Comment: @DavidBalažic when you want to accept just an `Orange` then your signature would be `addToSameStree(const Orange&)` and you accept just oranges. What is the issue?